# Excel Formula to sum cell over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel document that I need to have a totals sheet which takes in a specific cell over multiple sheets. It also needs to be expandable so I can just add the sheet name to a row or something and it will add it into the formula and the total.

Just a row like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqY4g.png) or something similar which could be used to add more sheets in future.

To give you an example currently, I am using a simple SUM function but it's not easily expandable:
`=SUM('Sheet1'!A6,'Sheet2'!A6,'Sheet3'!A6)`

I have had a look at INDIRECT but I can't find a way of having it expand to the length of an array eg. something like this:
`=SUM(INDIRECT(H3:H8,"!A6"))`

Would return all the values of A6 across each sheet named in H3:H8 evaluating like:
`=SUM(INDIRECT(H3,"!A6"),INDIRECT(H4,"!A6"),INDIRECT(H5,"!A6")...)`

If anyone has any ideas of what I can use to achieve this, it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a dynamic list of sheets for your sum formula, you may

1. Put the names of the sheets across which you would like to sum your cell(s) on a separate range of cells organized as a column range:

Sheet1

Sheet2

...

2. Convert the cells with the names of sheets into a table (select your range, then on the main menu panel select "Insert - Table").
3. Name the created table list (i.e. "List_of_Sheets")
4. To sum use the formula:
   =SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&List_of_Sheets&"'!A6")))
5. You may change the names of sheets in your table or add the new ones at the end of the table

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
`SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A6)`

You can add a Sheet named „Start“ and one named „End“.
Place all sheets you want to sum between the both. So you can use

`SUM(Start:End!A6)`